# How to plot ellipses with bray-curtis similarity values?

Tags: r, similarity, ellipse, vegan

I want to do an nMDS analysis and I want to add to my graph ellipses that represent the percentage of similarity of bray-curtis, but I do not know how to do it with R, this type of graphics you can do with PRIMER but I suppose with R as well.
How can I do it?

I want my graphic to look like this:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtomP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used PRIMER, and I do not know how these graphs are supposed to be drawn, but I have to guess from the graph you posted. It may be that you first get a cluster dendrogram (function `hclust`), and then cut it by tree height (function `cutree`) and then draw enclosing ellipses for these (`vegan::ordiellipse(..., kind = "ehull")`). If so, this should do the trick:

```
library(vegan)
data(BCI)
d <- vegdist(BCI)
ord <- metaMDS(d, trace=FALSE)
cl <- hclust(d, "average") # using average linkage
plot(cl, hang=-1)
rect.hclust(cl, h=0.4, border="red") # to see the clusters
rect.hclust(cl, h=0.5, border="cyan")
rect.hclust(cl, h=0.6, border="blue")
plot(ord) # then ordination & enclosing ellipses
ordiellipse(ord, cutree(cl, h=0.4), kind="ehull", col="red", lwd=2)
ordiellipse(ord, cutree(cl, h=0.5), kind="ehull", col="cyan", lwd=2)
ordiellipse(ord, cutree(cl, h=0.6), kind="ehull", col="blue", lwd=2)
```

I adjusted the limits for the current dendrogram. The `ordiellipse` will give you error message for every one-item class, but they are harmless (I got to clean the function from these).